# Lib(s)uinput: создание джойстика с несколькими осями и кнопками

Tags: linux, c

Изучая всё, что есть по `uinput`/`suinput`, так и не понял, как создать несколько кнопок на джойстике. На `python-uinput` пример  (псевдо-код—настоящий код будет на C):

```
import uinput

def main():
    events = (
        uinput.BTN_JOYSTICK,
        uinput.ABS_X + (0, 255, 0, 0),
        uinput.ABS_Y + (0, 255, 0, 0),
        )

    with uinput.Device(events) as device:
        for i in range(20):
            # syn=False to emit an "atomic" (5, 5) event.
            device.emit(uinput.ABS_X, 5, syn=False)
            device.emit(uinput.ABS_Y, 5)
        device.emit_click(uinput.BTN_JOYSTICK)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Хорошо, но мне надо создать несколько кнопок/осей. И как это сделать?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Lib(s)uinput: creating joystick with more than one button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39559063/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559063/libsuinput-creating-joystick-with-more-than-one-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(дублирую собственный ответ с английского Стека)

Если нужны дополнительные кнопки — значит, нужны дополнительные коды кнопок. Коды кнопок изначально определяются файлом `linux/input.h` для пользовательского пространства и [`uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h?h=v4.7) со стороны ядра. Для питоновой библиотеки коды отдублированы в [`ev.py`](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput/blob/master/src/ev.py). Как можно заметить, кодов довольно много, в данном случае интерес представляет всё что находится между `BTN_JOYSTICK` и `BTN_THUMBR` (но иногда используются и значения из набора `BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY`). Самые ходовые — `BTN_THUMB`, `BTN_PINKIE`, `BTN_[ABC]`, `BTN_SELECT` и `BTN_START`.

С дополнительными осями та же история, можно использовать что угодно из списка между `ABS_X` и `ABS_MISC`. Самые ходовые из дополнительных — `ABS_R[XYZ]` и `ABS_HAT0[XYZ]`.

Используются эти идентификаторы точно так же, как `BTN_JOYSTICK` с `ABS_X` и `ABS_Y`, тем самым и получаются дополнительные кнопки/оси.

Что ещё может быть интересно в этой связи, так это то, какие коды используются настоящими джойстиками, которые мы пытаемся проэмулировать. Эти коды можно получить с помощью программ  [evtest](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/) или [evemu](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/) (для этого, конечно, понадобятся настоящие джойстики). Некоторые широко распространённые джойстики (иксбоксовый и для ПиЭс3) [обсуждались (англ) здесь](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2013-April/008790.html) (как можно заметить, коды используемые джойстиками сильно разнятся, в зависимости от модели). Ну а чтобы узнать наверняка (или проэмулировать отсутствующий в физическом доступе джойстик) можно посмотреть на [ядерные драйвера для джойстиков](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/input/joystick?h=v4.7) (сугубо то, какие они используют значения из `BTN_` и `ABS_`).